# How to handle binding single entity with OData model

Tags: odata, sapui5

Suppose I wanted to have a text input where a user would type a product ID and press enter to load the product data into a view. I only want to load / view one product at a time.

I setup an event handler for my text input which gets the typed in product ID and then calls the `read` method for the odata model:

```js
onSubmit: function(){
    var prodID = sap.ui.getCore().byId("product_id").getValue();
    oData.read("/Products('" + prodID + "')", {
        success: function(){
            console.log(oData.getProperty("/Products('1')/Name")); // Outputs the product name
        },
        error: function(){}
    });
},
```

This successfully loads the data into the model. However, the model is "keyed" (for lack of a better term) by `/Products('1')` meaning that to access the data, you must know the product ID.

### Question

Where do I store the current product ID so that subsequent views know how to access the loaded product name?

I currently have a separate JSON model defined where I am storing the active product ID. In my subsequent view's `onBeforeRendering`, I am reading that active product ID and then creating a new context, but this doesn't seem right.

```js
var context = new sap.ui.model.Context(myModel, "/Products(1)");
this.getView().setBindingContext(context, "products");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do.

The standard: You have an XML view. Somewhere in your XML view you want to display the product name.

The most simple way is to bind your view to a specific product:

```
onSubmit: function() {
    ...
    // assuming oData is a variable which holds your model
    var sKey = oData.createKey("/Products", {
        Id: prodID // Assuming Id is the name of your key property
    });
    this.getView().bindElement({
        path: sKey,
        model: "myModelName" // if your model has no name, remove this line
    });
}
```

Then you can access the product name in your view:

```
<Text text="{myModelName>Name}" />
```

After binding the model to the view, you can always access the data (and the path) in your code using `oView.getBindingContext("myModelName");`

---

If you don't want to display the data but do some calculations: The success callback has two parameters. The first one contains the data.

```
oData.read(sKey, {
    success: function(oResult){
        ...
    }
 });
```

Comment: can you expand your answer slightly to explain how you would change the binding on subsequent views? The `onSubmit` will `router().navTo("AnotherPage")` - how do I change the binding path of the "AnotherPage" view?

Comment: To me this seems like a different question. When doing navTo you should provide the necessary keys as url parameters (`.navTo("anotherPage", { Id: prodID })`. Then in your subsequent view you have a handler (`Router.attachPatternMatched`) where you build a new path (`createKey` and/or concatenate strings) and bind it (`bindElement`)

Comment: `attachPatternMatched` to create an `onNavTo` event in my second view's controller is exactly the piece I was missing.